# How to work a Count clause into this query?

Tags: t-sql

I have a rather expensive query that returns a page of results:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT         
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY j.PostDate DESC) as Row,                                            
        FROM 
            JobListing j, 
            Location l, 
            City c,
            JobListing_Skill_XREF js,
            @SkillTable st            
        WHERE 
            DistanceBetween(@lat,@long, c.Lat,c.Long) <= @miles AND
            js.Skill_ID = st.id AND                     
            j.location = l.id AND
            j.id = js.JobListing_Id AND         
            l.CityID = c.Id             
    ) AS RESULTS
    WHERE Row Between (@PageNumber - 1) * @PageSize + 1 and (@PageNumber * @PageSize)
```

What I would like to do is also return the total count of the inner query so that I can calculate total pages.

However, I can't figure out how to thread a COUNT clause into it, and I really don't want to have to select this into a temp table or run it twice just to calculate page count.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM 
        (SELECT                 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY j.PostDate DESC) as Row,
                COUNT(*) OVER() AS total
                FROM 
                        JobListing j, 
                        Location l, 
                        City c,
                        JobListing_Skill_XREF js,
                        @SkillTable st                    
                WHERE 
                        DistanceBetween(@lat,@long, c.Lat,c.Long) <= @miles AND
                        js.Skill_ID = st.id AND                                         
                        j.location = l.id AND
                        j.id = js.JobListing_Id AND                     
                        l.CityID = c.Id                         
        ) AS RESULTS
        WHERE Row Between (@PageNumber - 1) * @PageSize + 1 and (@PageNumber * @PageSize)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx)?  Something like (can't test obviously :) ...

```
WITH R (Row) 
AS 
(
  SELECT                                 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY j.PostDate DESC) as Row,
  FROM JobListing j, Location l, City c, JobListing_Skill_XREF js,@SkillTable st
  WHERE DistanceBetween(@lat,@long, c.Lat,c.Long) <= @miles AND 
    js.Skill_ID = st.id AND
    j.location = l.id AND
    j.id = js.JobListing_Id AND
    l.CityID = c.Id      
)
SELECT R.*, COUNT(R.*) AS [Count] FROM R
WHERE R.Row Between (@PageNumber - 1) * 
  @PageSize + 1 and (@PageNumber * @PageSize)
```

Comment: That has the same issue, the Count(R.*) is not allowed in a query like that :(

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I was able to do, I'd love to know if people have better suggestions:

```
DECLARE @JobTable TABLE
(
    ...snip...
);
INSERT INTO @JobTable 
    SELECT          
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY j.PostDate DESC) as Row,
        j.*                     
        FROM 
            JobListing j, 
            Location l, 
            City c,
            JobListing_Skill_XREF js,
            @SkillTable st            
        WHERE 
            DistanceBetween(@lat,@long, c.Lat,c.Long) <= @miles AND
            js.Skill_ID = st.id AND                     
            j.location = l.id AND
            j.id = js.JobListing_Id AND         
            l.CityID = c.Id 

SELECT * 
         FROM @JobTable
         WHERE 
               Row BETWEEN 
                 (@PageNumber - 1) * @PageSize + 1 
                 AND (@PageNumber * @PageSize)


SELECT @TotalRows = Count(1) FROM @JobTable;
```